# HTML Button in blue color in android

Tags: html, css, button

I have a button  which when clicked get a blue selected color on whole button in android smartphone not in desktop browser. I tried with outline:none but nothing.

```
button:active {
       outline: none !important;
        }
```

Comment: will you plz add some code ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code for batter solution.

```
button:hover, 
button:active, 
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```